# Numerically stable form for vector rejection between two nearly parallel vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given two vectors $\vec{M}$ and $\vec{N}$, I want to compute the rejection between them : $oproj(\vec{N}, \vec{M}) = \vec{N}-(\vec{M}\cdot\vec{N})\vec{M}$.  For my purposes both input vectors are unit magnitude.  When they're very close to parallel the direct implementation of this equation loses a lot of precision.  Is there a way to compute it more stably in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{N}  = \vec{M} + \vec{E}$, where $\vec{E}$ is small.  Now for unit $\vec{M}$,$$\begin{aligned}oproj(\vec{N}, \vec{M}) &= \vec{M} + \vec{E} - (\vec{M} \cdot (\vec{M} + \vec{E})) \vec{M} \\&= \vec{E} - (\vec{M} \cdot \vec{E}) \vec{M}\end{aligned}$$

$\vec{E}$ will be near-orthogonal to $\vec{M}$, I'm not sure but this might reduce precision loss in the vector subtraction.  Whether the precision loss is merely shifted to the calculation of $\vec{E}$ is another thing...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer I wanted working from [this](https://stemandmusic.in/maths/mvt-algebra/vectorPR.php) page.

We can write the rejection as:

$$
oproj(\vec{N},\vec{M}) = \vec{N} - (\vec{M}\cdot\vec{N})\vec{M}
$$

Since $\vec{M}$ and $\vec{N}$ are unit magnitude this is equivalent to:

$$
oproj(\vec{N},\vec{M}) = (\vec{M}\cdot\vec{M})\vec{N} - (\vec{M}\cdot\vec{N})\vec{M}
$$

Which from the [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) is equivalent to:

$$
oproj(\vec{N},\vec{M}) = (\vec{M}\times\vec{N})\times\vec{M}
$$

You can compute the cross product very accurately with:

$$
\vec{M}\times\vec{N} = \frac{(\vec{M}-\vec{N})\times(\vec{M}+\vec{N})}{2}
$$

Even when $\vec{M}$ and $\vec{N}$ are very close to parallel, so the formula above will give you the rejection very accurately in that case.